# imagecropper with atribute image in primefaces doesn't crop although image is loaded

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

if I change

```
image="#{pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/upload
/#{fileUploadController.imagemTemporaria}"
```

and put

```
image="/imagens/#{fileUploadController.imagemTemporaria}"
```

the image is loaded. on the other hand, the method crop stops to work.

my images are in `F:\imagens-retaguarda\imagens`

my descriptor contains the following

```
 <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/imagens/* 
 dir=F:\imagens-retaguarda\" />
```

do you know why that happens?

below is my code.

```
<h:form>

    <p:outputPanel id="outputPanelUpload">

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputText value="Imagem" rendered="#{fileUploadController.exibeBotao}"/>
            <h:outputText value="Pré-visualização" rendered="#{fileUploadController.exibeBotao}"/>
            <p:imageCropper id="imageCropperImagemTemporaria" 
                value="#{fileUploadController.croppedImage}" 
                image="#{pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/upload/#{fileUploadController.imagemTemporaria}" 
                initialCoords="0,0,50,50" 
                maxSize="250,163" 
                minSize="30,30" />
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{fileUploadController.exibirPreVisualizacao}">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{fileUploadController.imagemEnviada}" cache="false"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <br/>

        <p:commandLink action="#{fileUploadController.crop}" update="outputPanelUpload" rendered="#{fileUploadController.exibeBotao}" value="Pré-visualizar" id="preVisualizar"/>

    </p:outputPanel>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.enviarImagem}" sizeLimit="1000000" auto="true" update="outputPanelUpload" label="Escolher"/>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a restriction on p:imageCropper that it doesnt work with alternate docroot in glassfish

> **from primefaces forum**
>
> *ImageCropper can crop local images in webroot and external images
>   located with http://. I don't think it is a bug but more like a
>   limitation as it doesn't support glassfish specific stuff like this.*

[link to above quoute by optimus](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2500).

Some friendly forum user has put together a codesnippet on how to construct the complete url. Havnt tested it myself, but conceptually it should work.

```
<p:imageCropper id="croppedImg" 
   value="#{controller.croppedImage}" 
   image="#{request.requestURL.substring(0, request.requestURL.length() - request.requestURI.length())}#{request.contextPath}/Screens/Image.png" 
   initialCoords="10,10,200,200" />
```

[link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31201)

Comment: What about if I want to allow the user post an image and keep it in his local machine? I'm talking about a possibility where I don't want to allow the user upload images from his local machine to the server, but keep the images in a specific path in his local machine.

Comment: I think you will need a javascript imagecropper component to do this on client-side only. I Think that is a new question really